# most_similar method in spacy/sense2vec prints everything

Tags: spacy, sense2vec

when I use `most_similar` method provided in the `sense2vec`, I get entire list of vocabulary printed. I think this is not correctly working. For an instance, I gave `50000000` just to test against "`decrease|VERB`", I have list of 188325

```
import spacy
from sense2vec import Sense2Vec
from sense2vec import Sense2VecComponent
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
s2v = Sense2Vec().from_disk("./s2v_old/")
most_similar = s2v.most_similar("decrease|VERB", n=50000000)
j =sorted(list(set([i.lower() for i in [' '.join(i[0].split('|')[0].split('_')) for i in most_similar] if i.isalpha()])))
print(len(j)) # 188325

print(j[:100]) 
['a',
 'aa',
 'aaa',
 'aaaa',
 'aaaaa',
 'aaaaaa',
 'aaaaaaa',
 'aaaaaaaa',
 'aaaaaaaaa',
 'aaaaaaaaaaa',
 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaand',...]
```

This is not what decrease means. I think there is a bug somewhere the probability computation just ignores the fact.

Answer (score 0):

If you request the most similar 50000000 words, you'll get the whole vocabulary. Try `n=3` or `n=10` instead:

```
s2v.most_similar("decrease|VERB", n=10)
# [('increase|VERB', 0.961), ('decreasing|VERB', 0.9295), ('increasing|VERB', 0.9273), ('decreases|VERB', 0.9251), ('increases|VERB', 0.9062), ('reducing|VERB', 0.904), ('increases|NOUN', 0.8928), ('decrease|NOUN', 0.8826), ('decreases|NOUN', 0.8751), ('reduce|VERB', 0.87)]
```

Notice that the results are already sorted by decreasing similarity score.

If you're trying to compare the string "decrease" to the string "50000000", then this isn't the correct method. Here's a link to the usage guide: https://github.com/explosion/sense2vec#-quickstart

Comment: Thanks. Right, I understand. But dont you think that gotta be validator say you cannot have over this many?  I know "50000000" is a crazy number, but could be an improvement?